# Unlocking the ethereum created in azure in azure shell

Tags: go-ethereum, javascript, console, microsoft-azure

I have created an ethereum account using ethereum proof of authority in azure and metamask I have been trying to unlock my ethereum account to use it with my website 
i entered  details like this in azure cloud shell
  Ssh -p 4000 adminuser@ethcyy5j4-dns-reg1.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com
Then its password and account like this
Then connecting to javascript console

it gives an error[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(address, password, unlockDuration)
```

**web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount** instead of **web3.personal.unlockAccount**.

The third parameter is the unlock duration in seconds, you can set it to 0 to unlock it until the end of the session.

Comment: I tried it but still it is not working